# SOAP, functions with in an object

Tags: php, soap

I am doing the following to expose the functions of an object via soap but it gives me as error

**Server**:

```
$soap_wrapper = new my_geo_soap_wrapper();
$soap_wrapper->set_geo_app($my_geo);
$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "urn://localhost/firstmobile"));
$server->setObject($soap_wrapper);
$server->handle();
```

**Client**:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location' => "http://127.0.0.1/firstmobile/simple_server.php",
    'uri'      => "http://127.0.0.1/firstmobile/"
    ));

$result = $client->__soapCall("geolocate",array($lat,$lng));
print $result;
```

**Error**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to a
>   member function geolocate() on a non-object in
>   /home/imran/projects/firstmobile/simple_client.php:15 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/imran/projects/firstmobile/simple_client.php(15):
>   SoapClient->__soapCall('geolocate', Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/imran/projects/firstmobile/simple_client.php on line 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is somewhere in the `my_geo_soap_wrapper` class. If I read your code, and the error, correctly, the SOAP call (`$client->__soapCall("geolocate",array($lat,$lng));`) is mapping to `$soap_wrapper->geolocate($lat,$lng)` on the SOAP server end.

Based purely on the name of the class, I wonder if this "my_geo_soap_wrapper" class is delegating to some other object, which also has a method called `geolocate`, and this is where the bug is? e.g.

```
class my_geo_soap_wrapper
{
     function geolocate($lat,$lng)
     {
         // Will blow up if $this->delegated_object hasn't been set correctly
         return $this->delegated_object->geolocate($lat,$lng);
     }
}
```

Pure speculation, but might suggest a route to investigate.